# responsive div width in a responsive page without using another media query

Tags: css, html

I have a section in the html page that has a back ground image, a title text at the left and a sign up form to the right.

I am using media queries to make it responsive. I am facing this problem even before media queries are triggered.

When screen size is 768+px (as in my fiddle, before the form slips to the next line), width of the title is fine at 15% (as it avoids overlap with the woman's face in the image and the form). But as screen size is enlarged, it seems too less and the lines can be in the same line.

This also happens when there is a media query for screen sizes between 506px and 768px.

Is there a way I can fix this without having to use anotehr media query?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
<section class="imageform">

<div class="container">
<div class="title">
<h1>  Title Title Title Title </h1>
<h3> Title Title Title, Title Title </h3> 
</div>

<form class="signup_form">

 <label for="Name"><strong> Your Name:</strong></label>
 <input type="text" id="Name_First" name="Name_First" required>
 <input type="text" id="Name_Last" name="Name_Last" required>   

 <label for="Email">Email Address:</label>
 <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" vrequired>

 <label for="RegPassword">Password:</label><input type="password" id="RegPassword" name="RegPassword" required>
</form>

 </section>  <!--End of imageform section -->
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fwkqos0c/6/

Comment: Well there aren't _any_ media queries in your example so how can we possibly tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution here would be to sent a relative font size on your `title` class. With relative I mean `em`'s. This means that your title font size automatically adjusts to the parent object's size.

More help:

http://css-tricks.com/why-ems/

(if my answer helped I'd be grateful for an approval)